# Inserts NULL - Node Js // MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

- I don´t know why this code inserts NULL.
- When the post request is sent I receive (from res.json(req.body) in index.js) an empty "{}"
- I´m using NodeJs, Express 4 and MongoDB.
- The name attributes in the post are the same than in the jade
  template. I have two forms in the same .jade but with differents names, obviously.
- **This is not all code, I just put the most important and what is related to the question**

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/registredUsers');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

    var db = req.db;

    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
    var userPassword = req.body.userpassword;

    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    collection.insert({
        username : userName,
        email : userEmail,
        password : userPassword
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            res.json(req.body);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: A quick tip when posting on Stack Overflow: Cut the question down to as small as you can.

Posting all your code here and asking us to fix it is usually going to leave you with very few responses and a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: @DrSatan1 I posted that code because I want you to know that I used router so my code is modular and I suppose that you want to know what is  written and what is not

Comment: Your edits are good. Upvoted. Sorry I don't know how to help with your problem.

Comment: what actually your `req.body.username` contains

Comment: @gypsyCoder nothing, its actually with Null value. If I change the code with for example, username: "hello", It inserts good in the database but it doesn´t appear in the json brackets declared in the last lines. I think the problem is in the variables and the req.body...

Comment: @VíctorElexpe I also think so ! It is not about insertion, It's about data you are getting from reg object

Comment: Are you sure you are sending `data` in your post call? otherwise `req.body` shouldnt be null. can you show how are you doing that post call?

Comment: @ravishankar that is the post call in the .jade file: `form#adduser.form-horizontal(name='adduser', action="/adduser", method="post", enctype='multipart/form-data')`. The structure of the input of the data is like that: `input#inputUserName.form-control(type='text', name="username", placeholder='Name', required=true)`

Comment: if you console `req.body` , does that gives you `null`? also, i suppose you have `name` attribute in all your `input` tags in the `form`. If not, then you should do that. It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/registredUsers');
```

At the top of your index.js and removing `var db = req.db` from the route.

Also, you can return the newly created document from the call back in your response.

Your `index.js` file would now look like this.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/registredUsers');

router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
    var userPassword = req.body.userpassword;

    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    collection.insert({
        username : userName,
        email : userEmail,
        password : userPassword
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            res.json(req.body); // <- here you could return the new object instead.
            // res.json(doc);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**edit**

To assist the OP I made the following suggestion:

Hardcode `var userName = 'test'` and return the created document in `res.json(doc)` in order to test that the database is updating.

Comment: The `router.post` should not go in index.js?

Comment: Hopefully that makes more sense. Essentially I think you should call db where you need to use it, and from the `monk` function directly. Also returning the newly created object is good convention as you have a return of the actual object in the db. Hence using `res.json(doc)`

Comment: With that changes, I get error 500 in POST, internal server error.

Comment: Wait, now in the json I receive the _id but not the username, email and password...

Comment: So the document is being created, but there are no values being passed in req.body? Why don't you hard code a value for userName, `var userName = 'test'` and then start by console logging the doc you get in the call back, before the response. `console.log(doc)` And have a look at the log to see if it is creating the document. This would indicate you have a separate issue from the OP on the front end with no values being passed.

Comment: Yes, If I force the values... `var userName = 'test'` all shows good, id, username, email, password... This means that the problem is req.body

Comment: Great, I think this closes your OP. If you need help with the frontend you should create a new question with the specific problem. This is often the way programming works, you solve one error at a time until the application runs.