# With hard code it works and with req.body don´t

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

If I hard code the variables the function inserts with the values but if I take `req.body` it inserts NULL.

It could be to have more than one form on the same page?

I put bodyParser urlencoded extended to true: `router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

**Form**

```
<form id="adduser" name="adduser" method="post" action="/adduser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" id="userpassword" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" id="userpassword" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input style="align:center;" class="form-control" type="password" name="userpassword" placeholder="Password" id="userpassword" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Registration" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**index.js**

```
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

var userName = req.body.username;
var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
var userPassword = req.body.userpassword;

var collection = db.get('usercollection');

collection.insert({
    username : "userName",
    email : "userEmail",
    password : "userPassword"
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        } else {
            // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser
            //res.location("userlist");
            // And forward to success page
            res.json(doc);
            //res.redirect("profile");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: console.log(req.body.username ) gives you what ?

Comment: are you sure there is something in your `req.body` . can you see somehting on `console.log(req.body)`. Also, i would suggest you to put bodyParser urlencoded extended back to false

Comment: Are you sending JSON? if so, it should be `bodyParser.json()`

Comment: @owaishanif786 Nothing appears on the console

Comment: @ravishankar it´s blank the console, don´t show nothing

Comment: @VíctorElexpe it means you are not filling your form properly. because if form is not properly submitting then it should give undefined. as right now its giving empty so there is no content when you submit form. can you show your form

Comment: `bodyParser.json()` instead of `res.json(doc)`? Gets me a null brackets in the npm console

Comment: @owaishanif786 i´ve just added the form to the question. See it.

Comment: As I described in my answer to your previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057898/inserts-null-node-js-mongodb The problem would appear to be on the front end, and more specifically with how you are sending data in your post request. You should post your form in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

From the body-parser [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme):

> *This does not handle multipart bodies*, due to their complex and typically large nature.

#### Solution #1: Use a different library

They recommend the following libraries if you want to use multipart/formdata:

[busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)

[multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)

[formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)

[multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

#### Solution #2: Change how you are encoding the form data

Change the `enctype` in your form to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and remove the `{ extended: false }` config object from bodyParser.

Because `urlencoded()` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it should do the trick.